# how to understand the "to his" in this sentence

Tags: possessives, ellipsis, possessive-pronouns

> In my own research, complaints from women about their husbands most often focused not on tangible inequities such as having given up the chance for a career to accompany a husband to his.

Hello, ladies and gentlemen, I want to consult you how to understand the last **to his** in this sentence. Which grammer structure it belongs?

Comment: to accompany a husband to his [career]. [Which grammar structure does it belong to?]

Comment: @Lambie
Thank you for replying, but I still feel confused. Because to my opinion, the sentence has already finished without **to his**: `...such as having given up the chance for a career to accompany a husband`. I don't know why the **to his** can exists.

Comment: The sentence is a bad one. It is too long, and to **accompany** someone **in** their career suggests working in the same type of work or profession. Since the hypothetical wife has given up the chance of a career, this does not make sense. Wives can, and often do, give up the chance of a career to **support** a husband **in** or **with**  his. 'To'  in 'to his' is the wrong preposition.

Comment: **It is a poor sentence. But it means what I said**. tangible inequities such as having given up the chance for a career to accompany a husband on his [career]. In English, accompany takes on: We accompanied him on the trip.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
Thanks. You said it does not make sense when **accompany...in**. Does it make no sense when **accompany...to** either? Because in my example above, the sentence is **to** case.

Comment: @Lambie - I accompanied bacon with chips and peas for a tasty lunch, then I accompanied my cat in her search for her ball of wool,  then I accompanied my mother in listening to Henry Normal on the radio. (He's very funny, by the way).

Comment: @hexiaole 'to' is wrong there.

Comment: @Lambie  
@MichaelHarvey
Thank you. I am confused and crazy now because I saw the example from cambridge dictionary: `"May I accompany you to the ball?" he asked her.`.
[link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD-%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD-%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93/accompany)

Comment: Accompany someone TO a place; Accompany someone ON a journey or trip. See? :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
So, in a word, the **accompany** in this case should use **in**, **on**, or **with** and this sentence is bad one. Hopefully I don't misunderstand your comments(But the sentence is extracted from our exam for postgraduate...).

Comment: *To* is fine in this metaphorical sense. The husband is gaining a career or travelling towards a career.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?  To be honest with you, I don't think it's actually a complete sentence. I'm still waiting for a "but" - as in  *most often focused not on X . . . but on Y."  Are you sure you have quoted this correctly?  It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Why do you think it is incomplete?  This sort of sentence is in common usage, both written and spoken.

Comment: @Chenmunka Because I would expect something like "In my own research, complaints from women about their husbands most often focused **not on** tangible inequities, such as having given up the chance for a career to accompany a husband to his, **but on** [something else]".  If there is no [something else] then why say **not on**?  Now if it had said **did not focus on**, then it would be fine.

Comment: Hexiaole, do you understand that the sense is that women often have to give up their job to go with their husband when _his_ job requires him to move to another city? I agree with Billy that there must have been more to the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The author avoided to repeat the word "career".
"... having given up the chance for a **career**
to accompany a husband to his **[career]**."